# Django Rest Framework POST fails: null value in column "cat_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I've recently converted my views to generic class-based views, however I've just noticed that POST requests fail on classes that have foreign-keys. The following is my code, followed by the error message.

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)


class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'cat_id')


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

**views.py**

```
class TaskList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    List all Tasks (OR for specified cat_id)
    """
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    filter_fields = ('cat_id',)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('tasks/', views.TaskList.as_view()),
```

**Error returned**

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "cat_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (51, buy-some, null).
```

**REQUEST content: JSON Object**

```
{
    "name": "buy-some",
    "cat_id": 1
}
```

Additionally, *Content-Type, Accept* headers are set to *application/json*.

**Category with id=1 exists**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably what you want is to define the field `cat` in your `TaskSerializer` to be a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`[(documentation here)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield), in your case would be:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cat = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'cat')
```

Then in your request just send the pk in the `"cat"` field like so:

```
{
    "name": "buy-some",
    "cat": 1
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Make sure to add the "serializers" before it so:

cat = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Category.objects.all())

Comment: @Sharpless512 I'm not sure what you mean here? Are you saying that you need to import from `serializers` rather than `relations`? 

When I poke through the source code it looks like `serializers` just imports from `relations` so there is still only one `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` class.